# Do any Linux distributions have a folder sync option (like briefcase in windows)?

Tags: rsync, synchronization

I want to keep my local folder synchronized with a network folder. Is there any folder synchronization utility or feature in Linux?

Comment: There's an unwarranted assumption behind the way you frame your question. Directory synchronization (“folder” is the Windows name for directory) is performed by any number of applications, not by a specific system component. So you won't find it amongst directory properties but amongst application lists.

Comment: ubuntu one is an exemple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous options for programs or even file systems that handle synchronization. I still use the ridiculously old [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/index.html) program to keep some of my home directories in sync. There are other programs similar to this as well. For easier situations that only require one way coping, `rsync` does the job nicely.

For cross platform synchronization, the ever popular [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) is always an options, although I would also look into more open alternatives such as [cloudfs](http://cloudfs.org/).

Another thing you really ought to consider is version control. At first it might not seem that it's suitable, but if you really analyze your synchronization problem, you might find that version control is just the ticket. This gives you far more freedom to change things in multiple places without breaking the synchronization (two way sync is always a challenge). The ability to track and merge different sets of changes can be invaluable. You might consider a distributed system like `git` or a central one like `subversion` depending on your application, although in all likelihood if you can get your head around the distributed model it will prove better in the long run.

Comment: +1 for the version control, even thou I must say that the simplicity and predictability behind the centralised model makes it hard to say that git is "always better" than svn. Sometimes easy and predictable is the better choice...

Comment: I didn't say it was "always better". In fact I sometimes still choose subversion over git. What I did say was that given the case of initially thinking you wanted directory synchronization, chances are git is going to be a more appropriate choice.

Comment: This case is very much about taste, since both git and svn will do the work quite well. But Torvalds has a nice speak on this topic http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8 he is a little bias thou.. :)

Comment: This is very outdated: I should update it with things like bittorrent-sync, owncloud, etc.